# (Wordpress) Image From Child Theme style.css Not Found

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Basically, there should be a checkbox image next to each service, loaded from the child theme's style.css using the "content" property.

This is what the css looks like from the child theme's style.css:

```
content: url(../clos/images/checkboxes.png) left top no-repeat !important;
```

Except the image is in that folder and in a child theme images folder too (tried to load it from there as well).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLs are case sensitive, so you should try this:
http://www.closlandscaping.com/wp-content/themes/Clos/images/checkboxes.png

It means you need to fix your css like this:

```
content: url(../Clos/images/checkboxes.png) left top no-repeat !important;
```